# How to install Numpy & pip3 for python3.x when they were installed in python2.7? Using Conda?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, conda

I want to write program in python3 (3.5), hence I installed python3 next to the pre-installed python2 (2.7) on Mac OS X El Captian.

Since my terminal runs python2.7 by default and Numpy is already installed for it, I put `alias python=python3` and expected to be able to install Numpy for python3. when I type `pip install numpy`. This was the generated message:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I also noticed that I have no `pip3` even though I am using python3: `python --version` returned `Python 3.5.2`, but `pip3 install numpy` got me `-bash: pip3: command not found`.

So my questions are:
1) How to install Numpy for python3.x when Numpy is installed on python2.x?
2) How to get pip3?
3) Is it better to use virtual environments, such as Conda, instead of juggling between python2 and python3 on the system?

Thank you from a total n00b

**------------------- Update -------------------**

Reinstalling python3 also fixed another problem in my case.
When I ran `brew doctor`, one of the warning message I got was:

`Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run brew link on these: python –`

This is a result of me running `brew unlink python` in order to fix

> "Python quit unexpectedly"

when I launch Vim and also

> "The ycmd server SHUT DOWN"

Both seem to relate to the YouCompleteMe autocomplete plugin which I downloaded for Python.

I got my idea of removing symlinks from [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/585) and [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/611)
However, Homebrew evidently did not like the absence of those 39 symlinks.

After uninstall (`brew uninstall python3`) and then re-install python3 (`brew install python3`) as Toby suggested, Homebrew gave me

```
You can install Python packages with  
pip3 install <package>
```

Then when I `pip3 install numpy` and `pip3 install scipy`, both executed successfully.

To my surprise, symlinks created during Python installation used to cause aforementioned error messages for Python and YouCompleteMe, but now I open python files using Vim without crash from a fresh Python installation, which definitely created the symlinks.

**------------------- Update2 ------------------**

After re-installing Anaconda2, the same YouCompleteMe error came back. I suspect Anaconda messed up symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way on a Mac is with Homebrew:

http://brew.sh/

Install Homebrew, then run:

`brew install python3 pip3`

Edit --

Python3 includes pip3, but Homebrew occasionally has trouble linking to the correct versions, depending on what has been installed. Running the following command:

`brew doctor`

And if you see errors relating to python or unlinked kegs, try running:

`brew uninstall python python3`

And reinstalling after checking `brew doctor`.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233519/pip3-linked-to-python-framework-instead-of-homebrew-usr-local-bin

Comment: I do use Homebrew, but ' brew install python3 pip3 ' got me:

Error: No available formula with the name "pip3" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: you might have pip3 already - try typing `pip3 install numpy`.

Comment: " -bash: pip3: command not found " is what I got in the question and now. :(

Comment: Did it install python3? what do you get if you type `which python3`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: okay, so you have python3, which should have installed pip3. What do you see if you run `brew doctor` ?

Comment: It will be long, but basically 3 warnings

Comment: Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Comment: Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Comment: Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
    python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118371/discussion-between-toby-and-sean).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the Anaconda Python distribution.

The main reasons are as such:

1. You will have a Python distribution that comes with `numpy` and the rest of the [Scientific Python](http://scipy.org) stack.
2. The Anaconda Python will be installed under your home directory, with no need for `sudo`-ing to install other packages.
3. `conda install [put_packagename_here]` works alongside `pip install [put_packagename_here]`; `conda install` is much 'cleaner' (IMHO, differing opinions are welcome).
4. If you have a Python 3 environment as your default, then `pip` works out-of-the-box without needing to remember to do `pip3`.
5. `conda environments` are easier to manage than `virtualenv` environments, in my opinion. And yes, you can have Python 2 alongside Python 3.
6. I once messed up my system Python environment - the one that came with my Mac - and it broke iPhoto (back in the day). Since then, I became convinced of needing separate, atomic environments for different projects.

I've detailed more reasons in a [personal blog post](http://www.ericmajinglong.com/2014/09/23/5-great-things-about-the-anaconda-distribution/).

Other distributions, of course, are all good, provided they give you what you need :).